# NAudio - beginners questions - running on 20ms buffer of audio file

Tags: c#, audio, wav, naudio

Doing my first steps in Audio prog and using NAudio, I'm trying to have a simple app that grabs a WAV file and getting 20ms of audio data each time till EOF. However I'm getting a bit confused with the buffer arrays and probably conversions. 
Is there a simple way someone can post in here?

Moreover I got confused with the following: 
When using `AudioFileReader readertest = new AudioFileReader(fileName)` I'm getting different metadata like bitrate of 32 and length of ~700000. 
However, when using the NAudio - `WaveFileReader file1 = new WaveFileReader(fileName)` I'm getting half values for the same audio file (bitrate = 16, length = ~350000). Also the encoding for the first is "IEEEFloat" while the latter is "PCM". Any explanations...?

Thanks v much!

Answer (score 2):

`AudioFileReader` is a wrapper around `WaveFileReader` (and supports several other file types), and auto-converts to IEEE float for you. If you want to read the audio directly into a byte array in whatever format it is in the WAV file, then you should just use `WaveFileReader`.